# Cannot import contacts with OpenInviter

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to use the OpenInviter for one of my project, I have followed the install steps and that worked fine, also I have deleted the "postinstall.php" from the directory.

Now when I try to get the contacts from any of the email provider it generates an error "Invalid Login. Please check the email and password you have provided and try again later !".

I have also tried the demo available on site, but it get the contacts from GMail only. Can you please help me with the error or guide me to any of the links. Waiting for the response. Thanks in advance